# How to use REG ADD with quotes in data string - PowerShell Script

Tags: registry, powershell-3.0

I an trying to run this command from within a powershell script and it just will not seem to work, I'm not sure what I have wrong here:

```
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AdobeARMservice /v ImagePath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common  Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\armsvc.exe\"" /f
```

I get the following error:

> x86 : The term 'x86' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program.

I think I have the inside quotes escaped right, is there something I am missing, it is driving me nuts. All I'm trying to do is put quotes around the path of the data string.

Comment: I know it has something to do with powershell seeing the (x86) as a snippet or something but I can't figure out how to make it just see all of it as one string.

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble comes from the fact that in PowerShell the way to use a " inside a string is not \" but `" so your can write :

```
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AdobeARMservice /v ImagePath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\armsvc.exe`"" /f
```

Your can also use single quote '

```
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AdobeARMservice /v ImagePath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\armsvc.exe"' /f
```

In the second case PowerShel vars `$xx` will not be expanded inside single quote string.